# Prove that $4(x^2+1)^3\leq 5(x^3+2)^2, x\geq 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

I want to prove that
$$4(x^2+1)^3\leq 5(x^3+2)^2$$
is true for all $x\geq 0$.

I tried to prove it by convexity arguments using Jenssen's Inequality, but that didn't seem to work. I tried to consider the function
$$f(x)=x^3$$
since we have a cubic term on both sides.

In terms of this $f$, our proof boils down to showing
$$4f(x^2+1)\leq 5(f(x)+2)^2$$
which doesn't seem to be an easy task to perform.

I feel like if the terms can be manipulated properly, we will be able to find an elegant form on which we can use our known inequalities. But, I can't do that myself.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you differentiate and find the zeroes of $f'(x)$, it's not too bad. You can find some simple linear factors and prove that the resulting cubic has no positive real roots using Descartes' rule of signs.

Comment: Your RHS should be with a power 2, not 3... Besides, it looks me non-natural to attempt using convexity Jensen's inequality in this complicated context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x\geq 0$, then
$$(x-2)^2\cdot (x^4+4x^3+4x+4)\geq 0$$
since $(x-2)^2>0$ as it is a square term, and $(x^4+4x^3+4x+4)\geq 0$ as all the terms are greater than or equal to zero.

Expand this expression and manipulate the terms to get
$$4(x^2+1)^3\leq 5(x^3+2)^2$$

Please check [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20%28x%20-%202%29%5E2%20%28x%5E4%20%2B%204%20x%5E3%20%2B%204%20x%20%2B%204%29) and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%204*%28x%5E2%2B1%29%5E3-5*%28x%5E3%2B2%29%5E2) in case you don't believe me :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Correct but this is not obvious with naked eye. I want to prove this with bare hands.

Comment: @KonstantinosDimoglou no no, this is quite obvious (but in a boring kind of way). In fact, I did it with bare hands. I just took the expression $4(x^2+1)^3-5(x^3+2)^2$ and started expanding it. Once you're done doing that (correctly), you just need to note that $x=2$ satisfies that expression twice (this is what we often call vanishing factor method), and the rest follows. I didn't show the steps in the answer because I was too lazy to type all that down.

Comment: Maybe, by doing Horner twice or with 1st and 2nd derivative at 2 we can see that 2 is double root of this expression. Anyway, thanks for helping

Comment: @KonstantinosDimoglou you're welcome, but what's a Horner?

Comment: https://www.math10.com/en/algebra/horner.html

Comment: @KonstantinosDimoglou Nice! I never knew this! This is quite interesting stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach :

Define :

$$f(x)=5(x^{3}+2)^{2}-4(x^{2}+1)^{3}$$

We have for $x\geq 2$ :

$$f'(x)\geq0$$

Or :

$$6x(x^4-8x^2+10x-4)\geq0$$

We have again $f'(0)=0$ and $f'(2)=0$

Remains to find the roots of a cubic for that we can use Cardano's formula and see that there is only one real roots wich is negative so useless.

We are done !

Comment: Sentence "Remains to find... useless" is cryptic...